# Stanford CS106a: some java applet errors that do not allow to run the programs

Tags: java

Wasnt able to solve the problems in this screen.

http://s8.postimage.org/n5osf76ed/qestions.jpg

All the code worked a month ago. 
What have I changed: I have a different version of eclipse (now:   Eclipse IDE for Java Developers  1.5.1.20120920-0737, don't know what the previous one was).

Messed with environment variable. Since this does not effect the ot

Please help.

Comment: Post your code, and the exception, here please, and not by way of an image.

Comment: See if this is relevant to your problem [Assignment 1 Karel not living in a world](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/see-cs106a/3vhSBSKFU84)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this solution mentioned in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/see-cs106a/3vhSBSKFU84).

> I just ran into this problem using standard (not Stanford) Eclipse. 
>   By now this is probably moot for you, but I'll post my solution for
>   future travelers.
>
> The launch configurations for Assignment 1 default to Applet, so the
>   containing Karel application isn't launched.  To solve this, create
>   and use new Application launch configurations for each file.
>
> If you already tried to run some of the files, delete the Applet
>   configs created so you can reuse the names:
>
> 1. Open the project properties (e.g. right click on Assignment 1 and select Properties).
> 2. Select Run/Debug Configurations.
> 3. Select and Delete each configuration.
> 4. Click OK.
>
> May the Force be with you.
>
> Create Application configs:
>
> 1. Right click on java file (e.g. CollectNewspaperKarel.java) and select Run As > Run Configurations...
> 2. Select Java Application in the left pane.
> 3. Click New Launch Configuration (the icon of a document with a +).
> 4. Type a name for the configuration and set its Main class to the associated file (e.g. CollectNewspaperKarel).
> 5. Click Apply then Run.  (This should run correctly and create a useful entry in the Run History.)
>
> Eclipse will still try to default to Applet, so you will henceforth
>   need to launch these configurations from the Run History (either from
>   the Run menu or the pull down on the run button).  If you accidentally
>   launch as default, it will add a useless Applet configuration to the
>   Run History (e.g. CollectNewspaperKarel (1) ).  You can delete this
>   from the Run Configurations dialog to keep the Run History tidy.

Comment: This helped. Thanks a lot. But I'm wondering is there a permanent solution for this problem? How do I get eclipse to run all my programs not as applets but as applications by default?

Comment: in step 4 check "Include inherited mains..." before clicking Search.

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse used in `CS106A` is customized for stanford and for "karel the robot" :)
Just download and install it again and things should work just fine.

Comment: No way to fix this without instaling the different version?

Comment: there might be ways.. but I have re installed the original version when I had an issue.